# More one angular directive module is not working on Pprod profile

Tags: jhipster

I am working on jhipster and I have two type of directive module in our jhipster app.first for index page and second for commmon directive.

When we run on Prod profile we get an exception :-

```
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'common-directives' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
 http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.11-build.2192+sha.e2173f9/$injector/nomod?p0=common-directives
 at D:/github_repo/gather-our-code/src/main/webapp/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1531
```

But i am running this on dev profile then it is working fine for me.

i have define to in our app as:

```
/* App Module */

angular.module('index-controllers', ['ngResource','index-services']);

angular.module('index-services', []);

angular.module('index-directives', ['index-services']);

angular.module('common-directives', []);

angular.module('indexApp', ['ngResource',
                             'ngRoute',
                             'index-services',
                             'index-controllers',
                             'index-directives',
                             'common-directives',
                             'http-auth-interceptor'
                             ]);
```

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21726619/how-to-run-more-than-one-angular-directive-modules-on-pprod

Comment: And did you import your JavaScript file in your index.html ?

Comment: Yes i have import all javaScript file in index.html